Encounter errors when deploying PieCloudDB with Kubernetes
When deploying PieCloudDB Database with Kubernetes, I consistently encounter errors, and resources aren't being scheduled as expected. Are there additional steps needed to take, either during or prior to the deployment process?

When deploying PieCloudDB Database, I need to work on the Kubernetes Master node to properly label the nodes where PieCloudDB will be deployed. The nodes are primarily designated for two roles: one for the Coordinator with the corresponding label control-plane, and the other for the Executor with the label data-plane. Here are the commands to perform these operations:
kubectllabel nodes 192.168.1.99 role=control-plane –overwrite
kubectllabel nodes 192.168.1.98 role=data-plane --overwrite
kubectllabel nodes 192.168.1.97 role=data-plane --overwrite

